# Is it correct to validate string length not equal to 36, when converting it into UUID

Tags: java, string, scala, uuid

I have a UUID string coming from an API which is of length 35, i.e.

73a31fa1-7414-4e4b-938b-0a37e80c28e

I have a logic written in scala something like this,

```
def stringToUuid(uuidStr: String) =
    if (uuidStr.length == 36) {
         Try(UUID.fromString(uuidStr))
           // throw some error if this failure
    }
    else
     {
 // throw some error saying not a valid UUID 
     }
```

I see that `73a31fa1-7414-4e4b-938b-0a37e80c28e` transforms to
`73a31fa1-7414-4e4b-938b-00a37e80c28e` i.e. an exta zero added after last `-` when I do

```
 UUID.fromString(uuidStr)
```

Why is the behavior like this ?
Is it not correct to check

```
 if (uuidStr.length == 36)
```

when I want to see if a String is not a valid UUID ?

Comment: Why do you need the extra check at all, since `UUID.fromString` will fail anyway?

Comment: The method `UUID.fromString()` won't fail in this case because it can split the string into 5 parts. If the last character is missing in the node identifier (the last part), the resulting UUID is WRONG. So you cant trust the simple validation from `UUID.fromString()`.

Answer (score 2):

When you look at the [code in jdk-8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/default/src/share/classes/java/util/UUID.java), you'll see that each component is converted to a hex string

```
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
            components[i] = "0x"+components[i];
```

That's how a leading zero in one of the components just get's padded. (not really padded but effectively)

But yes, technicially UUIDs string representations are defined as having the shape of  8-4-4-12 (length of characters). It just seems the implementation is a bit more lenient on the string format.
But it doesn't change the underlying 128-bit number if you have leading zeros in components or not.

Answer (score 1):

The specification of the string representation of an UUID according to RFC-4122 is

```
  UUID                   = time-low "-" time-mid "-"
                           time-high-and-version "-"
                           clock-seq-and-reserved
                           clock-seq-low "-" node
  time-low               = 4hexOctet
  time-mid               = 2hexOctet
  time-high-and-version  = 2hexOctet
  clock-seq-and-reserved = hexOctet
  clock-seq-low          = hexOctet
  node                   = 6hexOctet
  hexOctet               = hexDigit hexDigit
  hexDigit =
        "0" / "1" / "2" / "3" / "4" / "5" / "6" / "7" / "8" / "9" /
        "a" / "b" / "c" / "d" / "e" / "f" /
        "A" / "B" / "C" / "D" / "E" / "F"
```

So to be formally correct the last part must have 12 hex digits. Your string is therefore strictly speaking not a valid UUID.

Answer (score 1):

> The fromString() method of UUID class is used for the creation of UUID
> from the standard string representation of the same.

Its changing because you are calling that function again to generate another UUID based on the input you are getting.

**There is no issue with your length check.**

If you don't want to change the UUID string given by the API. Just don't call UUID.fromString(uuidStr) after the length check and proceed with your code.

Answer (score 1):

The UUID string generated from the API is truncating the last character from the node identifier. It should return exactly 36 chars, including the hyphens in their right positions. It's is formally INVALID and maybe wrong if the last char is truncated.

It's recommended to check why the API is returning of 35 chars instead of 36.

This is an validation example in Java that you can translate to Scala:

```java
public class Example1 {

    /**
     * Validate UUID WITH hyphens.
     * 
     * @param UUID a UUID string in canonical format 
     * @return true if valid
     */
    public static boolean isValid(String uuid) {

        if (uuid == null || uuid.length() != 36) {
            return false;
        }

        final char[] chars = uuid.toCharArray();

        int i = 0;
        // Firstly, check hexadecimal chars
        while (i < chars.length) {
            // Skip hyphen positions for now
            if (i == 8 || i == 13 || i == 18 || i == 23) {
                i++;
            }
            final int c = chars[i++];
            if (!((c >= 0x30 && c <= 0x39) || (c >= 0x61 && c <= 0x66) || (c >= 0x41 && c <= 0x46))) {
                // ASCII codes: 0-9, a-f, A-F
                return false;
            }
        }
        // Finally, check hyphens
        return (chars[8] == '-' && chars[13] == '-' && chars[18] == '-' && chars[23] == '-');
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String uuid = "73a31fa1-7414-4e4b-938b-0a37e80c28e";
        
        if(isValid(uuid)) {
            System.out.println("ok.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NOT VALID!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  static boolean isUUID(String string) {
    try {
        UUID.fromString(string);
        return true;
        }catch (Exception ex) {
       return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: You should add some explanation about the code to make answer more valuable and understandable.